# .bat script, 4 lists as data, input is an integer i, output is the rank of the list containing i

Tags: arrays, data-structures, batch-file

I need to write a script, in.bat, where

- the user inputs a 3 digits number (as a string) i.
- the script has 4 predefined groups of numbers, number from 1 to 4
- the script tests membership for i in the groups, and return the index of the group containing i.

I'm not familiar with declaring and initializing any kinds of data structure (e.g. list, arrays and the like) for batch files, so can someone help me on this?

Pseudo code:

```
::Returns 1,2,3,4,5 Depending on testNum passed
group1= <822-824,829,845,851,859,864,867>
group2= <826-828,830-839,843-844,847-850,852-854,860-862,883>
group3= <855-858,861,863,865>
group4= <877-882,884>
if %1 is member of group1 
return 1
if %1 is member of group2
return 2
if %1 is member of group3
return 3
if %1 is member of group4
return 4
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch does not have any formal complex data structures like arrays, lists, or objects. But you can emulate them. Here is an efficient solution that defines the groups with nearly the format as in your question.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

::Here is a small loop to test the routine
for %%N in (822,823,883,835,856,863,880,884) do (
  call :assignGroup %%N
  echo %%N is in group !group!
)
exit /b

:assignGroup  CaseNumber
:: The returning value is contained in variable GROUP
set group=0
for %%A in (
  "822-824,829,845,851,859,864,867"
  "826-828,830-839,843-844,847-850,852-854,860-862,883"
  "855-858,861,863,865"
  "877-882,884"
) do (
  set /a group+=1
  for %%B in (%%~A) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%C in ("%%B") do (
      if "%%C"=="%~1" exit /b
      if "%~1" gtr "%%C" if "%~1" leq "%%D" exit /b
    )
  )
)
::no group found so undefine the var
set "group="
exit /b
```

The above solution is fine for occasional calls. But if you were going to call the routine many thousands of times, then it would be better to initialize an array of valid values with assigned group numbers. Then each test becomes a direct read of the value, instead of having to call a routine. However, it is possible to abuse this technique. Assign enough values and each variable assignment gets slower and slower. You might also spend more time setting up the array than actually testing values.

Note there is no significance to the characters `[].` in the variable names. They could be stripped out of the variable names and the code would function the same. They are there only to aid in the understanding the intent of the variables.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

::initialize a sparse "array" that assigns a group to each valid case #
set group=0
for %%A in (
  "822-824,829,845,851,859,864,867"
  "826-828,830-839,843-844,847-850,852-854,860-862,883"
  "855-858,861,863,865"
  "877-882,884"
) do (
  set /a group+=1
  for %%B in (%%~A) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%C in ("%%B") do (
      if "%%D"=="" (
        set case[%%C].group=!group!
      ) else for /l %%N in (%%C 1 %%D) do (
        set case[%%N].group=!group!
      )
    )
  )
)

::Now test some values
for %%N in (822,823,883,835,856,863,880,884,900) do (
  if defined case[%%N].group (
    echo %%N is in !case[%%N].group!
  ) else (
    echo %%N is not in a group
  )
)
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

This will set `GROUP` to whatever group it finds the code in

```
set test=822,823,824,829,845,851,859,864,867
echo %test% | findstr %1>nul&&set group=1
set test=826,827,828,830,831,832,833,834,835,836,837,838,839,843,844,847,848,849,850,852,853,854,860,861,862,883
echo %test% | findstr %1>nul&&set group=2
set test=855,856,857,858,861,863,865
echo %test% | findstr %1>nul&&set group=3
set test=877,878,879,880,881,882,884
echo %test% | findstr %1>nul&&set group=4
```

if you want to use `ERRORLEVEL` to test the return value, then change the `SET GROUP=` to `EXIT /B`

Answer (score 1):

By no means perfect, but a working starting point. Save the following script as `group.bat` and call it with `group 878` to find out to which group 878 belongs to.

```
@echo off

SET group1=822-824,829,845,851,859,864,867
SET group2=826-828,830-839,843-844,847-850,852-854,860-862,883
SET group3=855-858,861,863,865
SET group4=877-882,884

CALL :IsInGroup %1 "%group1%"
IF Errorlevel 1 echo Group 1 & GOTO :EOF

CALL :IsInGroup %1 "%group2%"
IF Errorlevel 1 echo Group 2 & GOTO :EOF

CALL :IsInGroup %1 "%group3%"
IF Errorlevel 1 echo Group 3 & GOTO :EOF

CALL :IsInGroup %1 "%group4%"
IF Errorlevel 1 echo Group 4 & GOTO :EOF

echo Group not found
GOTO :EOF

:IsInGroup
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%i IN (%~2) DO (
    SET h=%%i
    SET g=!h:~3,1!
    SET /a lo=!h:~0,3!

    IF !g!. == -. (
        SET /a hi=!h:~4,3!
        IF %1 GEQ !lo! (
            IF %1 LEQ !hi! exit /B 1
        )
    ) ELSE (
        IF %1 EQU !lo! exit /B 1
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /B 0
```

The function `:IsInGroup` checks whether the first argument is contained in the list passed as the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of values to check for in each group is small, dbenhams second method (direct read of each array value) is the fastest. Any other method that process the values of each group in a FOR loop to do individual or range comparisons is slower. However, as the number of *individual elements* grows (counting each element included between a range) array value method get slower, as dbenhams indicated.

There is another approach to solve this problem using an aritmethic expression. For example, you may check if a variable is 829 or 845 with this command:

```
set /A result=(829-variable)*(845-variable)
```

If the variable have anyone of these two values the result is zero. To check if the variable is into a range, the expression is this:

```
set /A aux=(lowerLimit-variable)*(variable-upperLimit), result=(aux-1)/aux
```

Previous expression requires a small provision in case the variable is anyone of the limits (to manage the division by zero). The program below assemble the appropiate aritmethic expression for each of the groups; after that, checking each value is achieved with a maximum of 4 SET /A commands (one per group). This method is faster than individual testing of each value in a FOR loop and use just one variable per group, not per individual element.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Assemble testing expression for each group
set numGroup=0
for %%a in (
   "822-824,829,845,851,859,864,867"
   "826-828,830-839,843-844,847-850,852-854,860-862,883"
   "855-858,861,863,865"
   "877-882,884"
   ) do (
   set expr=1
   for %%b in (%%~a) do (
      for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%c in ("%%b") do (
         if "%%d" equ "" (
            rem Individual value: multiply previous expr by direct subtract
            set "expr=!expr!*(%%c-n^)"
         ) else (
            rem Range value pair: use range expression at this point, then continue
            set "expr=!expr!,a=r,r=0,b=(%%c-n^)*(n-%%d),r=(b-1)/b*a"
         )
      )
   )
   set /A numGroup+=1
   set expr[!numGroup!]=!expr!
)

rem Now test some values
for %%n in (822,823,883,835,855,856,858,863,880,884,900) do (
   call :assignGroup %%n
   echo %%n is in group !group!
)
goto :EOF

:assignGroup number
set /A n=%1, group=0
for /L %%i in (1,1,%numGroup%) do (
   set /A r=!expr[%%i]! 2> NUL
   if !r! equ 0 set group=%%i & exit /B 0
)
exit /B 1
```